# Why can't I append an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, append

I want to add user input to an array if it's a palindrome. I keep getting:

```
undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
```

when I run it.

Eventually I want to compare all values and find the highest, that is why I have the class in there.

```
class Palindrome
  attr_accessor :palindrome_array
  @palindrome_array = []

  def check_palindromic(variable)

    if variable.reverse == variable
      @palindrome_array << variable
    end
  end
end

a = Palindrome.new
puts "Enter a number"
i = gets.chomp()
a.check_palindromic(i)
```

I have been scratching my head over this. Can someone tell me what is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your object `a` didn't have the instance variable `@palindrome_array`, that you think it has. You need to do this:

```
a = Palindrome.new
a.palindrome_array=[]
puts "Enter a number"
i = gets.chomp()
a.check_palindromic(i)
```

Remove `@palindrome_array = []` from the this code as it has different meaning:

```
class Palindrome
  attr_accessor :palindrome_array
  @palindrome_array = []
```

Here is additional explanation:

```
class Palindrome
  attr_accessor :palindrome_array
  @palindrome_array = []
    def check_palindromic(variable)
         if variable.reverse == variable
            @palindrome_array << variable
         end
    end
 end  

a = Palindrome.new
Palindrome.instance_variables # => [:@palindrome_array]
a.instance_variables # => []
a.palindrome_array=[]
a.instance_variables # => [:@palindrome_array]
```

> I keep getting "undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass" when I run it.

Humm. This happens because `@palindrome_array` defined below class `Palindrome` is an instance variable belonging to the class object. Note this is not the same as a class variable and could not be referred to as `@@palindrome_array`, whereas `@palindrome_array` defined inside the `check_palindromic` method is an instance variable belonging to instances of `Palindrome`. They are two distinct variables and the first is accessible only in a class method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize all instance variables in your classes constructor:

```
class Palindrome
   ...
   def initialize 
      @palindome_array = []
   end
   ...
end
```

The way you have it currently, you are declaring an instance variable at the *class* level (which works because all classes inherit from Class)